# Alternatives for ActivityManager.getRecentTasks() in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Currently, the only way I have found to retrieve a history of recently launched applications through the android framework is with `ActivityManager.getRecentTasks()`.

Since the Android documentation site UI overhaul, I now see that a note has been added to this method:

> Note: this method is only intended for debugging and presenting task management user interfaces. This should never be used for core logic in an application, such as deciding between different behaviors based on the information found here. Such uses are not supported, and will likely break in the future. For example, if multiple applications can be actively running at the same time, assumptions made about the meaning of the data here for purposes of control flow will be incorrect.

What are the safer alternatives to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lollipop deprecated the method; however there is a new API that allows you to view app usage.

UsageStatsManager has some useful methods to see activity between an interval of time.
Hope this is sufficient for your needs!

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/package-summary.html